# How to use String variable value in 'create table' statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure in which i create new tables with the table_name being a variable.
but though

> select table_name;

returns variable value

> create table table_name(some_columns);

creates a table with name table_name and not the value.

Comment: You need to use a prepared statement.

Comment: Weird is that this posting is marked duplicate by you only *after* you answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute a prepared statement:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', table_name, ' (some_columns);';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you. Btw the ';' inside is redundant.